# Does frequent ajax call kill PC? How can I handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Every 10 seconds, it calls this ajax to reload the number of received mails.
However, it seems that my MacBook is getting so heated as time goes by, even when I'm doing nothing but staying at the same page in my application.

How should I handle this kind of transaction?

**refresh_mail_count.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    refreshMail();
});


function refreshMail() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/messages/refresh_mail",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
  });
}
```

**refresh_mail.js.erb**

```
$('#message_count').html("<%= j(render(:partial => 'layouts/message_received_count', :object => @message_count)) %>");
setTimeout(refreshMail,10000);
```

Comment: You can look at a push implementation so that any changes will be propagated to each browser.  No need to query every 10 seconds.  You can look at http://pusher.com/

Comment: @jvnill Thanks but it looks costy:(

Comment: How long does getting the mail count take?  Could it be close to 10 seconds?  Perhaps you need to increase the refresh time.

Comment: @RichardSchneider That's true. every time it calls, it should extend 5 seconds. and when the page is loaded, it resets to 10 seconds as default again. But how can I?

Answer (score 1):

The CPU gets hot when it *does work*: the question is then - is this work justified? That is, which process(es) use the CPU, and when?

This work will not come from the network request itself, as this is an IO operation of "low CPU usage", but consider what might *cause* some work:

1. The *processing* the response data (excessive/slow DOM manipulation), or
2. The *web-server itself* (slow/inefficient impl.), if running local, or
3. The AJAX requests might be piling up - this can lead to a [snowball effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_effect)<sup>1</sup>!

---

<sup>1</sup> Make sure to *only post a new request, 10 seconds **after** recieving the previous success/failure callback*.

Comment: looking at the code, I think she's already doing number 3. so look at 1 or 2.

Comment: @jvnill Yes, I misread the code initially. I believe you are correct. (I would still move the queue for the next request into a callback, however.)

Comment: @pst Thanks for the detailed answer. What exactly I can do for this situation if I'm doing number 1 and 2?

Comment: @cat Which process uses the CPU? - and when/how? Does it spike or is it a steady use? Does it increase? (Use "Monitor" to see.)  Also, what is does the "script" result look like?